# Electric motor will only start turning at lower voltages

Tags: motor, dc

I have a tiny DC motor directly connected to [this power supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042X8XOG). The motor starts just fine when the supply is set to 4.5V. I can then change the voltage to 6V and it continues to run just fine. However, if I try to start the motor at 6V it only runs in pulses (for about 100 milliseconds once every second). Also, if the motor is running at 6V and I apply significant load, it begins pulsing until I lower the voltage. I'm guessing both cases are explained by the larger current required to start the motor at a higher voltage, and to keep it running under load.

I have a few questions:

1. What is actually happening to cause the pulses?  Is my power supply overloading then "resetting" once every second?
2. Is there something very simple I can add into the circuit to allow it to start at higher voltages (a momentary current spike)?
3. Is there something very simple I can add into the circuit, perhaps a better power supply, to allow it to run under sustained load (a constant current increase)?

Comment: I'm just wondering how you measured that "100ms once every second". What you say is very strange to me, but I have this wild guess: maybe your cables are not well secured and if you start it too fast the torque moves the motor, disconnects it, then it returns to rest place and gets connected again, and so on.

Comment: Or at 6V the power supply is seeing the motor as a short circuit (it's pretty close to a dead short while starting!) and shutting down for a second...

Comment: What motor are you using?

Comment: @Vlad It's more likely that the motor is tripping the current protection circuitry on the power supply when it's starting up. Then the power supply resets and all starts again generating the pulse effect. I've expecienced that once and what I did to work around it was to replace the wall-wart by an equivalent set of AA bateries. They usually let you draw a few amps at start up without any limiting circuitry to get in the way.

Comment: The 100ms once every second is an estimation.

The motor is from a Dremal (that's all I know about it).

I think what Vlad described sounds exactly like what I'm seeing.  Batteries probably make the most sense from a current perspective, however, I was hoping to find a solution I could plug into the wall.

Comment: @Ricardo what you and Brian said is quite more likely. This behaviour reminded me of when I was 10 or so and I used to try hairdrier motors with 12V wall adapters and actually enjoyed the oscillating thing, also for the sparks. I connected one wire to the motor and held the other in my hand and found just the right distance to trigger the oscillations. The adapter was one of the old multi tap transformers, no current limiting there.

Comment: @Vlad Oh boy! The episode with the hairdrier and sparks at young age must have been a revelation for you to become an EE. You're also a strong contestant for a Darwin Award then, but fortunately you were not nominated, obviously.

Comment: @Ricardo I've got my darwin when I opened a disposable camera because I wanted to understand how the flash works. Luckily enough I had already learnt to use only one hand, keeping the left behind my back. I discharged the cap with my right index, it was hella painful... But I learnt to be extremily careful, always. I then hooked a long wire to the flash switch with a spst uswitch and used the camera to surprise family members hiding it on shelves and firing the flash at random. I was about 10, 10 to 12 I'd say.

Comment: Response to questions 2 and 3 - Yes. Get a bigger power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn our comments into an answer.

> 1. What is actually happening to cause the pulses? Is my power supply overloading then "resetting" once every second?

It's likely that the motor is tripping the current protection circuitry on the power supply when it's starting up. Then the power supply resets and all starts again generating the pulsing effect.

> 2.Is there something very simple I can add into the circuit to allow it to start at higher voltages (a momentary current spike)?
>
> 3.Is there something very simple I can add into the circuit, perhaps a better power supply, to allow it to run under sustained load (a constant current increase)?

In his comments, WhatRoughBeast suggests you get a bigger power supply.

I've expecienced that once and what I did to work around it was to replace the wall-wart by an equivalent set of AA bateries. They usually let you draw a few amps at start up without any limiting circuitry to get in the way. In your case, 4 AAs in an appropriate battery holder will do the trick.

Comment: Is there any solution for my question #2?  Perhaps a capacitor or something I can add to handle the momentary current spike?

Comment: Both WhatRoughBeast and I meant that a bigger power supply or AA batteries are the simplest thing to add to the circuit to make it start at higher voltages. That's the answer to both questions #2 and #3, but probably not the answer you want. I don't know any other way to make the motor start. But I'm not knowledgeable enough for you to take it as an expert opinion...

Comment: Understood.  I guess I'm very curious to know if there are any other options besides a larger power supply for #2.